# How to show all possible ordered outcomes of 4 dice

Tags: dice

I'm working on a project that requires I add a unique result for each and every possible ordered outcome of a roll of $4$ dice at one time. I'm stuck on how to show this in Excel or Google Sheets. Any ideas? Really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you call ordered outcomes ? Do you mean the values in the order they are drawn ($6^4$ ways), or the sorted values with duplicate 4-tuples removed ($126$ cases) ?

Comment: i mean that a result of: 1,2,1,1 is different than a result of 2,1,1,1. 

Said differently, it matters which die has which result

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formulas:

$$n\bmod6+1,\\\left\lfloor\frac n6\right\rfloor\bmod6+1,\\\left\lfloor\frac n{36}\right\rfloor\bmod6+1,\\\left\lfloor\frac n{216}\right\rfloor\bmod6+1$$ for $n$ from $0$ to $1295$. They give you the four dice.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to show the result of that in excel or google sheets?

Comment: @kvn2: of course, but I am not going to do all the work for you.

Comment: Fair enough haha. You've already been really helpful and I appreciate it. I'll play around w. the formulas in excel to see if i can figure it out. I guess I am just wondering if this 1 formula in 1 cell (repeated 1295 times) or 1 formula in 4 columns (repeated 1295 times)